# Why were so very similar names chosen for the European Council and Council of the European Union?

Tags: europe, political-history, names

There are two official EU institutions which have very similar names but do very different things:

- The [**European Council**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Council), which is a strategic body comprised of the heads of state or government of the member states, and
- the [**Council of the European Union**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council_of_the_European_Union) or just **Council**, which is one of the legislative bodies of the EU and consists of the national ministers (in varying combinations).

Obviously, this can lead to a lot of confusion. Why weren't more distinctive names chosen for those two institutions? (In particular, since there's also the [Council of Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council_of_Europe), which predates the European Union and is something completely differnt.)

Comment: They are both councils, and they are both European. You can only get so creative.

Comment: @SPavel: Well, "European Council of Heads" and "European Council of Ministers" would have been an option. But "European Council" and "Council of the European Union"? Seriously?

Comment: There was probably a subcommittee of a subcommittee of a committee of naming that decided this. If I know my politics, it was selected because it was the only name that *everyone* could agree on, not because it was the only idea they had.

Comment: OOC, are the names less confusing in French? Only a couple of countries in the EU speak English (about to become only one, I believe).

Comment: @T.E.D.: According to Wikipedia, it's *Conseil européen* and *Conseil de l'Union européenne* (or *Le Conseil*), which is even more similar. In German, which is my main language, it's pretty much the same as in English.

Comment: Well, they do different things but their composition of similar (members of the executive of each of the EU countries)